# How to make iterate through a 2d Vector?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to iterate through a 2d vector of Vec3, but I'm rather new to Rust and I'm not sure how. Here's what I got so far:

```
let vertList: Vec<Vec<Vec3>> = vec![vec![Vec3::new(0.,0.,0.);h as usize];w as usize];
for h in 0..vertList[?][?] {
    for w in 0..vertList[?][?] {
        //Some code for each pixel
    }
}
```

For further context, I want to use this 2d vector for storing the color values of a screen, and I want to scan through all pixels.

Comment: If it's a rectangle, you'd get better performance out of a single vector with `w*h` elements, and it would also make the iteration simpler. However, you need an extra field to store the dimensions, so it would be good to write a new structure for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop directly over a `Vec`’s elements, without involving a range of `0..len` indices, using [`Vec::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter):

```rust
for row in vertList.iter() {
    for pixel in row.iter() {
        // …
    }
}
```

(Alternatively, since `&Vec` can [become an iterator directly](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator-2) and `row` here is a borrow of a `Vec` either way,)

```rust
for row in &vertList {
    for pixel in row {
        // …
    }
}
```

And for completeness, the ranges you were looking for would end at [`vertList.len()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.len) and `vertList[h].len()` respectively.