# How to iterate over a two dimensional vector in rust?

Tags: vector, rust, 2d-vector

I have a mutable reference of vector of mutable references of vectors I want to iterate over the vector and then change the value of its elements.

```
let mut a = vec![1, 2, 3];
let mut b = vec![4, 5, 6];
let mut c = vec![&mut a , &mut b];
let mut v = &mut c;
```

I want to iterate over `v` and do operations on its elements
preferably using an iterator and not by indexing.(I specifically want to iterate over a reference of a vector of references of vector and not just a 2d vector)

Comment: This is probably a duplicate, but searching will take longer than [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bf9503b84b4d8dd1f7a2423267f46b9f). (Or, you could just go with two nested loops.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make iterate through a 2d Vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72843130/how-to-make-iterate-through-a-2d-vector)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let mut b = vec![4, 5, 6];
    let mut c = vec![&mut a, &mut b];
    let v = &mut c;

    for row in v.iter_mut() {
        for el in row.iter_mut() {
            *el *= 2;
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

```
[[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12]]
```

Or if you need the indices for the computation:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let mut b = vec![4, 5, 6];
    let mut c = vec![&mut a, &mut b];
    let v = &mut c;

    for (y, row) in v.iter_mut().enumerate() {
        for (x, el) in row.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            *el *= 2 * x + y;
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

```
[[0, 4, 12], [4, 15, 30]]
```